# getting a list of all registered usb hid devices in windows xp

Tags: c++, c, winapi, usb

i am trying query windows for a list of all usb hdi devices that are connected to my computer.
Somehow i the microsoft dokumentation is not exactly to helpfull for me. Can anybody please point me to something? I would like to use c/c++
Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what are you struggling with? Something a little more specific would certainly help your chances of getting an answer...

Comment: i am struggling basicicly with starting, i have worked only once with the winapi, and somehow i do not get where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you can find anything you want: https://github.com/signal11/hidapi

Comment: thanks! i had just found this. it is exactly what i need, but when i compile and run the command line test application. i just get the error: "unable to open device". Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: @mrblack I guess you are choosing the wrong descriptor of the device (I had the same problem). Also, not all devices can be opened. Try looking at the actual code and debug what's going wrong.